# Refreshing Cache from admin showing Fatal error: Call to a member function asArray() on boolean

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, cache, full-page-cache

Refreshing cache from back end

> Fatal error: Call to a member function asArray() on boolean in
>   /home/bulkpowd/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php
>   on line 420

When I open this file below code is written:

```
public function getFileLayoutUpdatesXml($area, $package, $theme, $storeId = null)
    {
        if (null === $storeId) {
            $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        }
        /* @var $design Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package */
        $design = Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package');
        $layoutXml = null;
        $elementClass = $this->getElementClass();
        $updatesRoot = Mage::app()->getConfig()->getNode($area.'/layout/updates');
        Mage::dispatchEvent('core_layout_update_updates_get_after', array('updates' => $updatesRoot));
        $updates = $updatesRoot->asArray();   // line no. 420 this line produce error
```

This error is happened not every time but occurs sometimes, but I don't know the exact case when it comes.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: this indicates that magento config object unable to get `frontend/layout/updates` node , you can try to debug it with  echo `Mage::app()->getConfig()->getNode('frontend/layout')->asNiceXml(); exit;` (or `adminhtml/layout` depending on where you are) to see which node is fails to load

Comment: But this error is not coming everytime. It comes once in a day or later.

Comment: When I tried above code with 'frontend/layout' its showed error Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element::asNiceâ€Œâ€‹Xml(), while worked with 'adminhtml/layout' and showed all xml files.

Answer (score 2):

I had something similar a long ago, and it was because of the php version.
At that time I had PHP version `5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4` and, from time to time, as you say, the conversion from `SimpleXMLElement` to array returned nothing.
It looks to me like the same thing but not sure about it.
Some [related but not really](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4430527/2047249) info can be found on SO.
So I advice you to check your PHP version, try and upgrade or a downgrade to see if this reproduces.

Comment: Is there any other way to resolve it because I can't upgrade php version on client sever. any other way means like doing some code hack in same file or something else ?

Comment: First of all, I don't know if this is the problem for you. I just added the answer here because it smelled like the problem I had a while back. Check the php version and if it's the same as the one I mentioned then for sure you need an upgrade. If it's different, I don't have any other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Check your XMLs,
maybe incorrect XML.

Also check logs, Magento logs & Apache/Nginx PHP